# How Can I do 1 Click Execute This T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL 2012 and I want all code to work at once. But giving me this error.
How should I follow a path.
Thanks.

```
BEGIN

USE 

CREATE TABLE PASSAPORT_TURU
(
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
ADI varchar(70) ,
KODU varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO PASSAPORT_TURU (ADI,KODU)
VALUES 
('Passaport Numarası','1'),
('Yabancı Hasta T.C. Kimliği','2'),
('Lütfen Seçim Yapınız.','3')

Alter table HASTA Add PASSAPORTTURU int CONSTRAINT FK_HASTA_PASSAPORT_TURU foreign key (PASSAPORTTURU) REFERENCES PASSAPORT_TURU(ID)

Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 1 where PASSAPORT IS NOT NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NULL and PASSAPORTTURU IS NULL

Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 3 where PASSAPORT IS NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NOT NULL

END;

GO
```

Comment: You need batch separator command `GO` before `update` statement.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Can u show me ı didn't understand clearly :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you doing DDL statement you need to use `GO` keyword after it, which mean execution of batches and scripts.

> These commands can be used to facilitate the readability and execution of batches and scripts.

make sure

```
Alter table HASTA Add PASSAPORTTURU int CONSTRAINT FK_HASTA_PASSAPORT_TURU foreign key (PASSAPORTTURU) REFERENCES PASSAPORT_TURU(ID)
```

was executed before insert the data.

```
BEGIN

USE [DLSaglikNet]

CREATE TABLE PASSAPORT_TURU ( ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), ADI varchar(70) , KODU varchar(20) )

INSERT INTO PASSAPORT_TURU (ADI,KODU) VALUES ('Passaport Numarası','1'), ('Yabancı Hasta T.C. Kimliği','2'), ('Lütfen Seçim Yapınız.','3')

Alter table HASTA Add PASSAPORTTURU int CONSTRAINT FK_HASTA_PASSAPORT_TURU foreign key (PASSAPORTTURU) REFERENCES PASSAPORT_TURU(ID)

GO -- <-- ADD GO HERE.

Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 1 where PASSAPORT IS NOT NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NULL and PASSAPORTTURU IS NULL

Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 3 where PASSAPORT IS NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NOT NULL

END;.
```

Answer (score 1):

you need first check  your alter with if  exist then add go to the end of your code:

```
if not exist(select PASSAPORTTURU from HASTA )
    Alter table HASTA Add PASSAPORTTURU int CONSTRAINT FK_HASTA_PASSAPORT_TURU foreign key (PASSAPORTTURU) REFERENCES PASSAPORT_TURU(ID)
go --here adding go
Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 1 where PASSAPORT IS NOT NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NULL and PASSAPORTTURU IS NULL
go
Update HASTA set PASSAPORTTURU = 3 where PASSAPORT IS NULL and TCKIMLIK IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Go keyword above your update statement lines.

```
Go
Update statements
```

This will ensure the alter statement has already happened before it tries to update the table.